# Ubuntu Won't install on my Desktop

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

Hardware Specs

- Motherboard: MSI 770-g45
- ATI HD5770 (H577FM1GD) connected to monitor through single DVI port
- AMD Phenom x4 Black Edition

When I try to boot up from a live cd/live usb all I get is a black screen, I can boot into the current Windows 7 mode fine. What can I do to remedy this situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try both the USB and CD method? How did you burn the .iso to the CD and USB? For the CD, burn at x4 speed to avoid data errors. If problems still occur, why not try the alternate .iso?

Comment: I tried both using the software creator and installed using the same usb stick on a different keyboard, will try the Alternate ISO

Comment: Is it using startup disk creator ? Do you have access to Windows ? If yes , you can try using Ultra ISO to burn the ISO to CD at x4 speed . Do comment if Alternate disk works =)

Comment: Alternate disk worked!

Comment: Now thats a good news =)

Answer (score 1):

Try directly installation, not "live" installation,
And whatever check your RAM.

Comment: Will try that and RAM is good

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (black screen when boot from CD, like monitor turned off), had to do the following to fix it (it was related to open source ATI driver that shipped with 11.10):

1. Install Ubuntu 11.04
2. Install ATI official driver from Additional Drivers
3. Perform upgrade from within to 11.10
4. Again, install ATI official driver from within 11.10 (not sure it was required, but it let me do it again so I did)

Answer (score 0):

Also, suggest you go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM and confirm with MD5 the ISO file you downloaded to burn with was not corrupted in transit.